# Entity Framework 6 and T4 - update WPF databindings

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 and looks like T4 generates just POCO classes from the database tables with no much additional functionality.

Earlier when I worked with EF4, I was getting UI updates automatically, for example

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedParent.children}"
```

were updated when adding to Parent's EntityCollection:

```
 Dim c As New children With {.parent = Parent}
_context.children.Add(c)
```

or deleting:

```
_context.children.Remove(someChildren)
```

With EF 6 the autogenerated classes seem to be just POCO. I don't see anymore for example AssociationChanged event nor is there OnPropertyChanging and OnPropertyChanged events either.

On top, the collections are defined as HashSets

```
Public Overridable Property children As ICollection(Of children) = New HashSet(Of children )
```

**How to update the databindings automatically when EntityObjects are added or deleted into context**? (I want EF4 functionality back!)

Comment: Have you seen this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx?

Comment: I had missed that doc but it saved me thanks. In short, I needed to edit the .tt file and change ICollections and HashSets to ObservableCollections so WPF can catch up with changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx) explains how to do this.